# How to loop through only Custom Document libraries in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, document-library, custom-list

I want to loop through all custom document libraries (not OOB) in sharepoint 2010. What is specific method/function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this.

but you might be able to do something using the SPList.TemplateFeatureId and SPList.IsCatalog

Most people don't properly set the TemplateFeatureId when creating custom lists. So if the TemplateFeatureId is not an empty guid and it isn't in the catalog (default lists in the catalog have an empty guid)

```
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            if(!list.isCatalog && list.TemplateFeatureId == Guid.Empty ){
            // List might just be custom

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get any custom document libraries :

```
using (SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
 {
    using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
    {

       string[] libNames = { "myDocLib1", "myDocLib2", "myDocLib3", "myDocLib4" }
       SPDocumentLibrary docLib = null;
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       {    
        docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists[libNames[i]];     
       }
    }
 }
```